# Simplify my ListView (with Intent, setOnItemClick etc)

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, onitemclicklistener

I write a activity with a ListView. Now I want to know, is it possible to simplify my code (make it shorter).

An example is under the codeblock

```
package de.bodprod.dkr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MediMenue extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> medi_menue_items;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.medi_menue);
        ListView antidotListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);        


        medi_menue_items = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

        HashMap<String , Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        item.put("title", "Antidots");
        item.put("desc", "Toxine und die Gegenmittel");
        item.put("class_open", "MediAntidotList");
        medi_menue_items.add(item);

        item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        item.put("title", "Notfallmedikamente");
        item.put("desc", "Dosierungen, Gegenanzeigen u.v.m.");
        item.put("class_open", "MediNotmediList");
        medi_menue_items.add(item);

        ListView lv;
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); 
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent in = new Intent();
                String class_open = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.class_open)).getText().toString();
                if(class_open.equals("MediAntidotList")){
                    in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediAntidotList.class);
                }else if(class_open.equals("MediNotmediList")){
                    in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediNotmediList.class);
                }
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });     

        final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.medi_menue, medi_menue_items);
        antidotListView.setAdapter(adapter);            

    }
    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>>{
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> Strings) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, Strings);
        }
        private class ViewHolder{
            TextView class_open, title, desc;
        }
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView==null){        
                convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.medi_menue_item, null);
                viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.class_open=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.class_open);
                viewHolder.title=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.medi_menue_name);
                viewHolder.desc=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.medi_menue_desc);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else{
                viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.class_open.setText(medi_menue_items.get(position).get("class_open").toString());
            viewHolder.title.setText(medi_menue_items.get(position).get("title").toString());
            viewHolder.desc.setText(medi_menue_items.get(position).get("desc").toString());
            return convertView;
        }
    }   
}
```

For example: In the OnItemClickListener I get the id from the list item, and than I use with if and else. But the id is the same like the name from the activity, is it possible to say the new Intent, that it should open the class with the name wich is in the String class_open? Something like this:

```
        String class_open = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.class_open)).getText().toString();
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), <class_open>.class);
        startActivity(in);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you are using ListActivity, you don't need to call setOnListItemClick handler on the list itself, just override this method from the ListActivity:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id);
```

So you can have this:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent in = new Intent();
    String class_open = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.class_open)).getText().toString();
    if(class_open.equals("MediAntidotList")){
                in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediAntidotList.class);
            }else if(class_open.equals("MediNotmediList")){
                in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediNotmediList.class);
            }
    startActivity(in);

}
```

Then to answer your other question, you can try the Java reflection to get a class:

```
String class_open = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.class_open)).getText().toString();
Class c = Class.forName("com.yourpackagename." + class_open );
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going for a long shot here since I haven't tried this myself. But I see you got a ViewHolder class that you don't show. If you really want to change ur onItemClick code, you could store an intent in every ViewHolder, which is set in your getView(...). This way you can get the viewholder tag in onItemClick and get the intent from that tag and start it.

Example:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
 {
    // Get the intent that u stored in this viewholder
    ViewHolder clicked = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    Intent toStart = clicked.getIntent();
    startActivity(toStart);          
 }
```

And you dont need to set the onItemClick listener since you are extending from ListActivity, just override it.

To implement all this, you need to do some changes in getView() in your adapter. I'm sure you can figure out what!